# span has offset in firefox but not in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

my html is really simple

```
<div class="btns">
    <div id="green">    <span class="btn btn-block btn-large btn-success disabled green_btn">Green</span>

    </div>
    <div id="red">
        <form class="button_to" >
            <div>
                <input class="btn btn-block btn-large btn-danger red_btn" type="submit"
                value="Red">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.btns {
    position: relative;
}

#green, #red {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49%;
    position: relative;
}
.green_btn, .red_btn {
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

as you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/HajHV/9/

on chrome it looks like this

[image: on chrome]

but on firefox its

[image: on firefox]

I don't understand this difference. There is nothing in html/css that should matter for this.. How do I fix it?

Comment: I see you are using bootstrap , why didnt you used default bootstrap class to get the same effect . that you are trying to achieve .

Comment: try eliminating the whitespace between divs, i.e. `</div><div id="red">`

Comment: You're seeing this because of a bug in Chrome's inline-block implementation: it doesn't do what the spec says with the baseline....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `display: inline-block;` to `.green_btn, .red_btn {...}`

Answer (score 1):

Add `vertical-align:top`

```
#green, #red {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49%;
    position: relative; vertical-align:top
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HajHV/10/)**

Answer (score 0):

Or, try:

```
.btns {
    position: relative;
}

#green, #red {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49%;
    position: relative;
}
.green_btn, .red_btn {
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}
#green {
    float:left;
}

#red {
    margin-left: 4px;
}
```